# How do you set a validationQuery when using karaf + Ops4j jdbc + apache DBCP?

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-karaf, ops4j

I've followed the tutorial here: http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access which explains how to set up a datasource in Karaf using apache DBCP wrapped by Ops4J JDBC.

You can set properties on the underlying object pool using the "pool" property prefix, but there is no way I can see to set the "validationQuery" property, probably because this is not a property of the underlying pool, but the BasicDataSource itself. I need to set this property because I am experiencing connection timeouts on our dev server, which sometimes break our nightly integration tests.

Can this be done?

Comment: Pax jdbc does not use a BasicDataSource so I am not sure if you can set this parameter at all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know of an equivalent property, or another way to solve the problem? Most datasources I've looked at (Hikari, BasicDataSource, C3PO) have a way of specifying a lightweight query to periodically test the underlying connections before handing them over to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to set the validation query independent from the BasicDataSource. There is org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.setValidationQuery.

We use a PoolableManagedConnectionFactory internally in pax jdbc. Currently there is no way to set this property but I added a jira issue to add this option: https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXJDBC-70

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks. Looking forward to the next release!

Comment: I added the code for this now and resolved the issue above. So next release should have it. I would appreciate if you could check out the pax-jdbc source and build/test it for your case.

Comment: Thanks for doing it so fast. I've checked out, compiled and tested, and the fix seems to work. I've debugged karaf, and I can see the validation query is getting set on the factory correctly. Not so easy to simulate the idle timeouts, but I'm confident that everything is working properly on your side. Thanks again.